# TOLVEN installation: Test Database and LDAP Connections After ConfigPhase1

Tags: centos, postgresql, centos6, openldap, tolven

I am trying to install tolven, and following the manual http://wiki.tolven.org/index.php/Installation_Guide

My linux system info is as follows:

```
root@localhost:/> cat /etc/issue
**CentOS release 6.4 (Final)**
root@localhost:/> arch
**x86_64**
```

Everything was going fine as per the manual untill the **step 7.7 "Test Database and LDAP Connections After ConfigPhase1"**

```
root@localhost:/> service postgresql status
postmaster (pid  26942) is running...
root@localhost:/> 
root@localhost:/> ps aux|grep slapd
root     21160  0.0  0.2 231572 14652 ?        Ssl  21:47   0:00 slapd -f slapd.conf -h ldaps://
root     21496  0.0  0.0 103236   840 pts/1    S+   23:23   0:00 grep --color=yes slapd
root@localhost:/> 
root@localhost:/> cd /usr/local/tolven-RC1/bin
root@localhost:/> ./tpf.sh -plugin org.tolven.postgresqlmgr -testAdminDB
Please enter config directory: /usr/local/tolven-config
0 [main] INFO root  - Start log4j - Configuration: file:/usr/local/tolven-RC1/bin/tolven-log4j.xml, logFileName: /usr/local/tolven-RC1/log/tolven.log
23:21:26,024 INFO  [TPFBoot] TPF Version: 0.0.10
23:21:26,024 INFO  [TPFBoot] Loaded configDir /usr/local/tolven-config
23:21:26,034 INFO  [TPFBoot] Generated boot.properties: /tmp/tpf_4158526156312314572_boot.properties
23:21:26,044 INFO  [TolvenApplicationInitializer] logging system initialized
23:21:26,044 INFO  [TolvenApplicationInitializer] application root is /usr/local/tolven-RC1/bin
23:21:26,090 INFO  [PluginRegistryImpl] configured, stopOnError=true, isValidating=false
23:21:26,391 INFO  [PluginRegistryImpl] plug-in and fragment descriptors registered - 89
23:21:26,533 INFO  [TolvenApplicationInitializer] integrity check done: errors - 0, warnings - 0
23:21:26,533 INFO  [TolvenApplicationInitializer] application plug-in is org.tolven.command
23:21:26,564 WARN  [TolvenApplication] Remote library unavailable: tolvenRemoteClient.jar because Could not retrieve library: tolvenRemoteClient.jar
23:21:26,566 WARN  [TolvenApplication] Remote library unavailable: tolvenRemoteClient.jar because Could not retrieve library: tolvenRemoteClient.jar
23:21:26,660 INFO  [AdminAssembler] Prompt via System.in with: Enter your password: 
Enter your password: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load secret key from /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/admin-encryptedSecretKey
        at org.tolven.security.password.PasswordHolder.loadSecretKey(PasswordHolder.java:411)
        at org.tolven.security.password.PasswordHolder.loadPasswordStore(PasswordHolder.java:302)
        at org.tolven.assembler.admin.AdminAssembler.setupAdminPasswordStoreCredentials(AdminAssembler.java:425)
        at org.tolven.assembler.admin.AdminAssembler.execute(AdminAssembler.java:153)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.execute(TolvenApplication.java:163)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.execute(TolvenApplication.java:153)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.startApplication(TolvenApplication.java:91)
        at org.java.plugin.boot.Boot.boot(Boot.java:346)
        at org.java.plugin.boot.Boot.main(Boot.java:243)
        at org.tolven.plugin.boot.TPFBoot.main(TPFBoot.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load keystore from /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/tolvendev-admin.jks
        at org.tolven.security.password.PasswordHolder.getKeyStore(PasswordHolder.java:124)
        at org.tolven.security.password.PasswordHolder.loadSecretKey(PasswordHolder.java:405)
        ... 13 more
Application start failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute: org.tolven.assembler.admin
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.execute(TolvenApplication.java:168)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.execute(TolvenApplication.java:153)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.startApplication(TolvenApplication.java:91)
        at org.java.plugin.boot.Boot.boot(Boot.java:346)
        at org.java.plugin.boot.Boot.main(Boot.java:243)
        at org.tolven.plugin.boot.TPFBoot.main(TPFBoot.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication.execute(TolvenApplication.java:163)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load encrypted SecretKey /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/admin-encryptedSecretKey
Could not load secret key from /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/admin-encryptedSecretKey
        at org.tolven.security.password.PasswordHolder.loadPasswordStore(PasswordHolder.java:305)
        at org.tolven.assembler.admin.AdminAssembler.setupAdminPasswordStoreCredentials(AdminAssembler.java:425)
        at org.tolven.assembler.admin.AdminAssembler.execute(AdminAssembler.java:153)
        ... 10 more


root@localhost:/> cat /usr/local/tolven-RC1/log/tolven.log
2013-08-25 23:21:26,024 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TPFBoot] TPF Version: 0.0.10
2013-08-25 23:21:26,024 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TPFBoot] Loaded configDir /usr/local/tolven-config
2013-08-25 23:21:26,034 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TPFBoot] Generated boot.properties: /tmp/tpf_4158526156312314572_boot.properties
2013-08-25 23:21:26,044 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TolvenApplicationInitializer] logging system initialized
2013-08-25 23:21:26,044 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TolvenApplicationInitializer] application root is /usr/local/tolven-RC1/bin
2013-08-25 23:21:26,090 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.registry.xml.PluginRegistryImpl] configured, stopOnError=true, isValidating=false
2013-08-25 23:21:26,391 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.registry.xml.PluginRegistryImpl] plug-in and fragment descriptors registered - 89
2013-08-25 23:21:26,533 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TolvenApplicationInitializer] integrity check done: errors - 0, warnings - 0
2013-08-25 23:21:26,533 INFO  [org.tolven.plugin.boot.TolvenApplicationInitializer] application plug-in is org.tolven.command
2013-08-25 23:21:26,564 WARN  [org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication] Remote library unavailable: tolvenRemoteClient.jar because Could not retrieve library: tolvenRemoteClient.jar
2013-08-25 23:21:26,566 WARN  [org.tolven.command.TolvenApplication] Remote library unavailable: tolvenRemoteClient.jar because Could not retrieve library: tolvenRemoteClient.jar
2013-08-25 23:21:26,660 INFO  [org.tolven.assembler.admin.AdminAssembler] Prompt via System.in with: Enter your password: (I tried 'tolven' here)
```

I am unable to find any reason for the error and solution to troubleshoot this.
Thanks in advance for your kind suggestion.

I want to request the moderators to add a tag **"tolven"** for this question.

Comment: Please read http://serverfault.com/editing-help

Comment: Have you checked into the message `Could not load secret key from /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/admin-encryptedSecretKey`?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that msg and the file has read permission for everyone (644).
I even tried with chmod 777 /usr/local/tolven-config/credentials/admin/admin-encryptedSecretKey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password should be **'sysadmin'** instead of **'tolven'**

**'tolven'** was the **cipher pass-phrase** for the **ssl-private-key** generated.
I had made a mistake in step 7.2 'Set Up Environment Variables'

```
$ cd <install-dir>/bin  
$ . ./tpfenv.sh
```

I used './tpfenv.sh' instead of '. ./tpfenv.sh' and the 3 environment variables
TOLVEN_USER, TOLVEN_PASSWORD and TOLVEN_CONFIG_DIR was not available.

```
$ echo $TOLVEN_USER $TOLVEN_PASSWORD $TOLVEN_CONFIG_DIR
```

above command was showing no output
But, if I use **". ./tpfenv.sh"** it shows following output

```
admin sysadmin /usr/local/tolven-config
```